# How to know if a value in firebase has increased or decreased?

Tags: java, android, firebase, service, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an android app in which there is this option to Follow/Unfollow a user. Whenever someone follows him, the counter in `FirebaseDatabase` gets increased by 1 and when someone unfollows him, the counter gets decreased by 1.

I'm trying to notify user every time someone follows him by starting a service as soon as he leave the app and writing the code in the `Service`.

Here's the code in `onCreate()` of the Service:

```
    firebaseDatabaseFollowers.child("***").child("***").child("followers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                b = sharedPref2.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_NOTIF_FOLLOW, true);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "b: " + String.valueOf(b), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                    if (String.valueOf(b).equals("true")) {

                        final int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotificationService());
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), m, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "database is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The notification part is working fine. The only problem is that the notification is delivered even when someone unfollows the user and I don't want this to happen.

So, is there any way to know that if the counter in `FirebaseDatabase` increased or decreased so that I can notify accordingly?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would store a global variable in your app that holds the number of followers that the user currently has. When the database sends down new info, you can compare it to the number you have saved by using if new number > or < than saved number. This could be problematic, however, in case the user goes offline and comes back online after, say 1 user unfollowed and 2 others followed. In this case, the user would just get a +1 follower notification. What I might recommend is sending down the username of the user that followed, just like Instagram does. For example, "John Smith followed you!" or "James Smith unfollowed you!".

Comment: am I supposed to save the 'global variable that holds the number of followers that the user currently has' in a `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: I don't program with Android, so I don't know what that means - sorry! I guess what would make more sense is to save the variable so that it can be accessed in any class you need (public versus private)